# Mysql insert syntax error, cant find the location

Tags: mysql, database, syntax

I am new to Stackoverflow ( new to asking questions that is, i have been using advice and help from questions not asked by myself and i want to thank for that.)
But to cut straight to the chase, i have an mysql error and have been changing " to ' and used a lot of escaping methods, but i still keep getting mysql errors.
It is a syntax error
**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'condition,district,gender_allowed,interior,internet,max_nr_people,mediation_cost' at line 1

```
        INSERT INTO kamerfeed (title
        ,link
        ,description
        ,minimum_price
        ,daisycon_unique_id
        ,category
        ,internal_id
        ,address
        ,area
        ,city
        ,condition
        ,district
        ,gender_allowed
        ,interior
        ,internet
        ,max_nr_people
        ,mediation_costs
        ,own_kitchen
        ,own_shower
        ,pets_allowed
        ,smoking_allowed
        ,toilet
        ,zipcode
        ,source)
        VALUES 
        (
        "Kamer Abersonlaan, Wageningen"
        ,"http://ds1.nl/c/?wi=162822&si=1271&li=1234742&dl=details-kamer-abersonlaan-in-wageningen%2F125379.html&ws="
        ,"Royale kamer met balkon op het oosten. Gedeelde woonkamer met balkon op het westen, eetkeuken, badkamer met douche, bad, wastafel, toilet en wasmachine. Eigen koelkast. Neem contact op, ook als de huur hoog lijkt. Kijken kost niets!..."
        ,"550.00","Df18a0377e4b0f8d53fa068cbb006ba49"
        ,"Kamers in Wageningen"
        ,"125379"
        ,"Abersonlaan"
        ,"26"
        ,"Wageningen"
        ,"Goed"
        ,"Ja"
        ,"Man"
        ,"Gemeubileerd"
        ,"Ja"
        ,"1"
        ,"nee"
        ,"Gedeeld"
        ,"Gedeeld"
        ,"Ja"
        ,"Ja"
        ,"Gedeeld"
        ,"6703GE"
        ,"kamer"
        )
```

i have been trying for more than an hour now, but i still cant figure out whats wrong with is. It is probably something easy, but i cant seem to find out myself.
thanks in advance.

Comment: String literals should be enclosed in single quotes, not double quotes (but I think MySQL does allow this non-standard usage though). And numbers should not be enclosed in quotes at all

Comment: Can you: `SHOW CREATE TABLE kamerfeed`?

Comment: `condition` might be a reserved word, try to enclose it with backticks.

Comment: did you miss a `,` near `zipcode`?

Comment: Iam not missing a comma near zipcode, at least not in the error on my page, arunmoezhi edited the code ( thank you for that) so it has a better overview of what goes wrong, but tje comma before zipcode is present in my error.

Comment: @Beatnut: My bad. I made a mistake in the edit. You can go ahead and update the query.

Comment: Thanks a_horse_with_no_name, that seemed to be the problem, condition is reserved, after changing it to roomcondition it didnt return an error and everything was loaded in my table. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You seem to be missing a comma at `zipcode`:

```
,toilet
zipcode
,source
```

And `condition` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html), place back-ticks around it:

## See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a57ba/1)

Answer (score 2):

Are you missing a comma before `zipcode`?

Also, good job @a_horse_with_no_name: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a `comma`, should be:

```
INSERT INTO kamerfeed (title
,link
,description
,minimum_price
,daisycon_unique_id
,category
,internal_id
,address
,area
,city
,condition
,district
,gender_allowed
,interior
,internet
,max_nr_people
,mediation_costs
,own_kitchen
,own_shower
,pets_allowed
,smoking_allowed
,toilet
,zipcode
,source)
    ...
```